# Clear sqlalchemy reflection cache

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy's reflection tools to get a Table object. I do this because these tables are dynamic and tables/columns can change. Here's the code I'm using:

```
def getTableByReflection(self, tableName, metadata, engine):

    return Table(tableName, metadata, autoload = True, autoload_with = engine)
```

The problem is that when the above code is run twice it seems to return the same results regardless of whether or not the columns have changed. I have tried refreshing using the `mysession.refresh(mytable)` but that fails because the table is not attached to any metadata - which makes sense but then why am I seeing cached results?

Is there any way to tell the metadata/engine/session to forget about this table and let me load it cleanly?

Comment: Not attached to any metadata? So what do you pass as a value of `metadata` parameter?

Comment: I use the same metadata object that I use in the rest of my code. The error is `<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError'> Class 'sqlalchemy.schema.Table' is not mapped` - I took this to mean it was to do with metadata but maybe not?

Comment: What if you pass in a newly created, fresh metadata instance. Does that work?

Comment: It does! If I create it like `return Table(tableName, MetaData(), autoload = True, autoload_with = engine)` then the problems are gone but I'm not sure how this affects performance. Thanks codeape!

Comment: Great. I added the comment as an answer, so you can give me the accept points if you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass in a newly created, fresh metadata instance.

Comment: How? Details are always convenient.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3070319/3571

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to [codeape](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3571/codeape)'s comment above I was able to fix the problem by changing the syntax to:

```
def getTableByReflection(self, tableName, metadata, engine):

    return Table(tableName, MetaData(), autoload = True, autoload_with = engine)
```

So passing in a new `MetaData()` instance each time. This probably affects performance but it's ok for me in this part of my app.

All credit to [codeape](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3571/codeape)