# Why an UnmappedInstanceError while populating a database using Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, orm, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to SQLAlchemy and am using Flask-SQLAlchemy for my current project. I'm getting an error that has me stumped:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'flask_sqlalchemy._BoundDeclarativeMeta' is not mapped; was a class (app.thing.Thing) supplied where an instance was required?
```

I've tried changing the notation in the instatiation, and moving some things around. Could the problem be related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3068408/2441384), or something else?

Here is my module (`thing.py`) with the class that inherits from Flask-SQLAlchemy's `db.Model` (like SQLAlchemy's `Base` class):

```
from app import db

class Thing(db.Model):
    indiv_id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key = True)
    stuff_1 = db.Column(db.INTEGER)
    stuff_2 = db.Column(db.INTEGER)
    some_stuff = db.Column(db.BLOB)

    def __init__():
        pass
```

And here is my call to populate the database in the `thing_wrangler.py` module:

```
import thing
from app import db

def populate_database(number_to_add):
    for each_thing in range(number_to_add):
        a_thing = thing.Thing
        a_thing.stuff_1 = 1
        a_thing.stuff_2 = 2
        a_thing.some_stuff = [1,2,3,4,5]
        db.session.add(a_thing)
    db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your model. Instead of `a_thing = thing.Thing`, it should be `a_thing = thing.Thing()`. Notice the parentheses. Since you overrode `__init__`, you also need to fix it so it takes `self` as the first argument.